# Can't get my head around basic vector identity $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{r}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Let $\bf r$ be a vector and $r$ be its magnitude. I want to evaluate $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{r}$. My working is
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{r}&=\frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{dt}\\ &=\frac{-1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dt}(\bf r\cdot\hat r)\\ &=\frac{-1}{r^2}(\dot{\bf{r}}\cdot\bf{\hat r}+\bf{ r\cdot \frac{d\hat{\bf{r} }}{dt}})
\end{aligned}$$
I'm pretty sure the answer should be $\frac{-1}{r^2}(\bf{\dot r\cdot \hat r})$ but I can't see why $\bf{ r\cdot \frac{d\hat{\bf{r} }}{dt}}=0$. I get that $\hat {\bf r}$ is constant in magnitude, but its direction changes.

Comment: Why do you think that the answer shouldn't have the second term? It should

Comment: If a vector has constant magnitude, then its derivative is perpendicular to it.  So that second dot product is $0$.

Comment: The direction change must be orthogonal to the actual direction, hence the dot product vanishes.

Comment: @B.Goddard Oh haha how silly of me! $\bf{r \cdot \frac{d \hat r}{dt}}=|r|( \bf{\hat r \cdot \frac{d\hat r}{dt}})$. Facepalm.

Comment: How's $\hat r$ defined?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed answer is not quite right.  For clarity, let $\|r\|$ be the norm of $r$ and $\langle.,.\rangle$ the corresponding inner product. The we find, as $\|r\|=\sqrt{\langle r,r\rangle}$ that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{\|r\|}
=-\frac{1}{\|r\|^2}\frac{1}{2\|r\|}\cdot2\langle r,\dot r\rangle=-\frac{1}{\|r\|^3}\langle r,\dot r\rangle,$$
which is in your (slightly foggy) notation
$$-\frac{1}{r^3}\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{\dot r}.$$

Comment: Perhaps (because "constant magnitude") $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ denotes the _unit_ radial field $\mathbf{r}/r$...?

Comment: Maybe, but are we supposed to be hieroscopists? ;)

Comment: Certainly not, hence the upvote. :)